# changes does not reflected in tempate django till server is refreshed

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to update the logo of my website and there is no problem till uploading it and loading it in template for the first time. But, when i try to update the logo, it does not reflect in the template until i make some changes to intentionally refresh the Django server or i break and run it again. I am using DJANGO 1.11.3 and PYTHON 3. I am still very new to django, if anyone need anything else other than the below content, i will provide. Thanks

**Header.html**

```
<a href="#" class="logo">
<!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
<!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
{% load static %}
{% for i in company_logo %}
 <img class="NO-CACHE" src = "/{{ i.Company_logo }}" alt="Profile Picture" style="height:50px;width:120px">
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Company_master

company_logo = Company_master.objects.all()

def companys_logo(request):
company_data = Company_master.objects.all()
return render(request,'service/companys_logo.html',{'company_logo':company_logo, 'company_data':company_data})

def post_company_logo(request):
company_id = request.POST.get('inp_id_hidden')
company_logo = request.FILES.get('inp_company_logo')
company_obj = Company_master.objects.get(Company_code = company_id)
company_obj.Company_logo = company_logo
company_obj.save()
company_obj.refresh_from_db()
return redirect("service:company_details")
```

**models.py**

```
class Company_master(models.Model):
Company_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
Company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Jurisdiction = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Email_service = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
Email_accounts = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
PAN_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
GSTIN_no = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
Dealer_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
Bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
Branch_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
Branch_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
Account_no = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
IFSC_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
SMTP = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
Fax = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
CIN_no = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
Principal = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
Working_hrs = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
Proxy = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
Password = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
Port_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
Phone_nos = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Mobile_nos = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Company_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/service/media/', null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.Company_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. When i update the logo, it does not fetch the new value from the database as the below variable was declared globally which was preventing the new value to come in.

```
# views.py
company_logo = Company_master.objects.all()
```

This variable should be included in every page so as to recall it again and again whenever the page is refreshed, like this

```
def companys_logo(request):
company_logo = Company_master.objects.all()
company_data = Company_master.objects.all()
return render(request,'service/companys_logo.html',{'company_logo':company_logo, 'company_data':company_data})
```